# Cant create a record within viewset custom view based on url parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hello I have a django rest framework view set. For the create view I want to create a custom view that will create a new record based on two different parameters that are passed on through the url which are namespace and path. I looked at the documentation but i couldnt find how it should look like. I am noit sure what I need to do in order to create a record based on both url parameters.

I basically tried setting the create to a CreateAPIView but it did not work

```
class PreferenceViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Preference.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else: 
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Preference.objects.all()
        serializer = PreferenceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        queryset = Preference.objects.all()
        serializer = PreferenceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to setup the create to create a preference with the two parameters that are passe in the url

```
path('preferences/<str:namespace>/<str:path>', preference_path, name='preference-path'),
```

I wanted it to create a new object with the namespace and path

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in 2 steps:

1. Add the url arguments to serializer context from viewset
2. Override `create` method on the serializer and use data passed on the context to create the record

So, at first override `get_serializer_context` method to add the arguments to context:

```
class PreferenceViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._namespace = None
        self._path = None
    ...
    ...

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update(namespace=self._namespace, path=self._path)
        return context

    def create(self, request):
        self._namespace = self.kwargs['namespace']
        self._path = self.kwargs['path']

        queryset = Preference.objects.all()
        serializer = PreferenceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now, you can access the parameters inside the overriden `create` method of the serializer and create the record as you want e.g.:

```
class PreferenceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        namespace = self.context['namespace']
        path = self.context['path']
        # Create object here based on the params
```